# Is two way ssl possible with aws document db?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

Does AWS DocumentDB support authenticating clients with SSL?I've downloaded rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem and got rds-truststore.jks by following the aws link "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled".Specifying it in truststore,I can successfully connect to document db.

For two way ssl,I've created keystore using self-signed certificate following the link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/appendix/security/appendixA-openssl-ca/. I'm able to connect to documentdb by specifying any keystore,even by specifying rds-truststore.jks in both truststore and keystore also.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon DocumentDB doesn't support x509 certificate based authentication, only username/password authentication.
As the service is continually improving, stay tuned for new [releases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/release-notes.html) .